# How is this character Kylo Ren's grandfather?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

I've only seen *The Force Awakens* but what I know is that Darth Vader is Luke's father, giving rise to the famous "I am your father" quote.

> So is Darth Vader really Ren's grandfather or is he just calling him that?

Answer (score 5):

## Yes, he really is.  Kylo Ren is Leia's son, and hence Darth Vader's grandson.

Leia is Anakin Skywalker's / Darth Vader's daughter, as first revealed in *Return of the Jedi*.  She is Luke's twin sister.

In *The Force Awakens*, it is emphasized several times that both Han and Leia are Kylo Ren's parents.

For instance,

> **LEIA (to HAN):** *If you see our son* [Ben Solo / Kylo Ren], *bring him home.*

Comment: LOL, this question reminds of `Captain America: Civil War` when spiderman is fight giant Antman and says, `Hey, you guys remember that really old movie, The Empire Strikes Back when they.....`